# Flutter - Row text overflow issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

using this code i am getting text overflow error.
How to resolve this?

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyColor.bgLightColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child:Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 24,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/current_outlet_icon.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Current Outlet",
                      style: textStyleWith12500(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(  
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/location_pin.png",
                      height: 18,
                      width: 18,
                      color: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "WTC Tower, Los Angeless sbdjkds jsbksdb kcbk",  // here
                      style: textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blackColor),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
    )
```

this is my text style and others textstyle is like this

```
TextStyle textStyleWith12500(Color color) {
  return TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      fontSize: MyFontSizes.t12Size,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      color: color);
```

Comment: Can you provide your text style so we see the full picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solve in two ways. One is using *overflow* attribute and another is wrapping with widget.
Overflow attribute with ellipse type will solve it with dots are end which means there are more text.

**Wrapping with  Flexible :**

```
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                      'WTC Tower, Los Angeless sbdjkds jsbksdb kcbk',
                  style: textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blackColor)
                    ),
                )
```

This will send long text to next line and will not get overflow issue. Hope it helps.